# How to initialse a class before creating a list of the class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to C#

I have Test class where the constructor definition looks like this

```
public Test(
        ILogger<Test> log,
        ITelemetryClient telemetry
    )
    {
        this.log = log;
        this.telemetry = telemetry;
    }
```

now in another place I need to create a list of this class

```
 IEnumerable<Test?> test= new List<Test?>() {....}
```

now how do I initialise this class to set those values before creating the List or how to pass values to the class constructor?

Comment: You'll need to define (or find) a stub/fake/mock implementation of each of those interfaces. For `ILogger` you can use `NullLoggerFactory` which is built-in to MEL (but means you'll lose all logged messages, which may be undesirable), as for `ITelemetryClient`, you'll probably have to reimplement that yourself.

Comment: you can simply use List initializer - var list = new List<Test?> () { new Test(logger, telemetry), new Test(logger, telemetry), new Test(logger, telemetry)} and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have inject the `ILogger` and `Itelementry` when creating Test class. You will also need to  inject them when you want a instance.
You can try the following code.
Test.cs

```
    public class Test
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Test> logger;

        public Test(ILogger<Test> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<Test> logger;

        public ValuesController( ILogger<Test> logger)
        { 
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void Method1()
        {
            var a = new List<Test>()
            {
                new Test(logger){Name="Tom"},
                new Test(logger){Name="Kite"}
            };
        }
    }
```

Or like this

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly List<Test> tests;
        private readonly ILogger<Test> logger;

        public ValuesController(ILogger<Test> logger)
        {
            this.tests = new List<Test>()
            {
                new Test(logger){Name="Tom"},
                new Test(logger){Name="Kite"}
            };

            this.logger = logger;
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public void Method1()
        {
            Console.Write(tests);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add text to explain your answer.